# Tableau Public Integration

Tags: tableau-api

We are using Tableau Public server in order to host a few public reports which will be embedded into our secure website.

When users access my website and the Tableau reports, will the client browser interact with Tableau Public server directly or will it interact via the web server to the Tableau Public server?

If it interacts via Tableau Public server, would there be a unnecessary performance delay?

Answer (score 1):

When you embed a view into your web page, the Tableau Public server(s) are rendering it. So the user is "connecting" to Tableau Public directly.

You would have to measure performance yourself, but I would assume that Tableau's servers are faster than yours. If that is true, you should not see any performance impact - especially since there is no authentication done with Tableau Public.

Comment: Thanks for the info , is there a way I can verify that my client browser is connecting directly to tableau public ?

Comment: Yea, open the developer tools available in your browser and monitor the "Network" section. You should be able to see every request that is made. At least one should be a Tableau domain.